# Oracle VM provisioning from dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq, oraclevm, pxe-boot

I have Oracle VM 2.2.0 and a provisioning server (dhcp/tftp/http) based on dnsmasq.
A VM that it is configure too boot from the network, is receiving the IP, but it is failing to boot. The error displayed by gPXE 0.9.3+ is:

`No filename or root path specified`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by adding `dhcp-no-override` to dnsmasq configuration.